# Pmax of columns ending with a given string

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to conditionally mutate a new column representing the `pmax()` of columns ending with "_n" for a given row.  I know I can do this by explicitly specifying the column names, but I would prefer to have this be the result of a call to `ends_with()` or similar.

I have tried `mutate_at()` and plain `mutate()`.  My general thought is that I need to pass a `vars(ends_with("_n"))` to something, but I'm just missing that something.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs, gear) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(disp),
            sd = sd(disp),
            n = n()) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, round, 1) %>% 
  mutate(mean_sd = paste0(mean, " (", sd, ")")) %>% 
  select(-mean, -sd) %>%
  group_by(vs, gear) %>% 
  nest(n, mean_sd, .key = "summary") %>% 
  spread(key = vs, value = summary) %>% 
  unnest(`0`, `1`, .sep = "_")
```

```
   gear `0_n` `0_mean_sd`   `1_n` `1_mean_sd` 
  <dbl> <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>       
1     3    12 357.6 (71.8)      3 201 (72)    
2     4     2 160 (0)          10 115.6 (38.5)
3     5     4 229.3 (113.9)     1 95.1 (NA)
```

edit: both answers are much appreciated.  Cheers!

Comment: There is no variable ending with `_n` in mtcars. How exactly you mean ending with `_n`?

Comment: After running the code I provided, summary columns are created.  Some of them end in "_n" to indicate counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using the unquote-splice operator. We can `select` columns that we want to compare and then splice them as vectors into `pmax`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(gear = c(3, 4, 5), `0_n` = c(12L, 2L, 4L), `0_mean_sd` = c("357.6 (71.8)", "160 (0)", "229.3 (113.9)"), `1_n` = c(3L, 10L, 1L), `1_mean_sd` = c("201 (72)", "115.6 (38.5)", "95.1 (NA)")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
tbl %>%
  mutate(pmax = pmax(!!!select(., ends_with("_n"))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>    gear `0_n` `0_mean_sd`   `1_n` `1_mean_sd`   pmax
#>   <dbl> <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>        <int>
#> 1     3    12 357.6 (71.8)      3 201 (72)        12
#> 2     4     2 160 (0)          10 115.6 (38.5)    10
#> 3     5     4 229.3 (113.9)     1 95.1 (NA)        4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A base R version, just as an alternative:

```
tbl <- structure(list(gear = c(3, 4, 5), `0_n` = c(12L, 2L, 4L), `0_mean_sd` = c("357.6 (71.8)", "160 (0)", "229.3 (113.9)"), `1_n` = c(3L, 10L, 1L), `1_mean_sd` = c("201 (72)", "115.6 (38.5)", "95.1 (NA)")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
tbl$pmax <- do.call(pmax,as.list(dat[,grepl("_n$",names(dat))]))
```